# Need Help in Saving RTF as TXT as a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, razor

I was able to read a RTF file (Data table) and get this to read to a string as below.

```cpp
Stream rtftxt = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
int size = Convert.ToInt32(rtftxt.Length);
Byte[] rtf = new Byte[size];
rtftxt.Read(rtf, 0, size);
string FileText=System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(rtf);
```

I Need to either remove Rich text formatting or if possible, save this as a TXT in stream and read this stream again. Any help and suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do a Google search for "convert RTF to plain text". You'll find lots of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinForms [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) control can be used to convert rich text into plain text programmatically without actually placing the control on a form.

The following code reads rich text from an input stream and writes the resulting plain text to an output stream.

```
var box = new RichTextBox();
var reader = new StreamReader(input);
box.Rtf = reader.ReadToEnd();
var writer = new StreamWriter(output);
writer.Write(box.Text);
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: This is an Excellent solution. But my dev environment is C# .NET MVC 3 with Razor engine. So all I have as controls are the HTML controls to be used in cshtml with jquery. Sorry for not mentioning earlier that this is for a web app. Not windows.

Comment: You can still use this approach from a web project so long as you don't mind adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: @Nathan I dont think you can use windows form in a web application.